# Canvas in html using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello ...</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;
    var canvasElem = $("<canvas id='my-canvas' width='" + CANVAS_WIDTH + "' height='" + CANVAS_HEIGHT + "'></canvas>");
    $(canvasElem).appendTo('body') ; 


    var canvas = canvasElem.get(0); 

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    context.fillRect(0,0,400,200);



  </script>

  <body>
  Testing ...
  </body>
</html>
```

The code above is not drawing canvas. But if I write something after `</script>` for example replacing 6th line with following
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>here`
 then canvas is drawn. I can't figure out the error in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is not ready at the time your script is executed. You can either put the script inside `body` or add an event listener that executes just after the DOM is ready:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;
    var canvasElem = $("<canvas id='my-canvas' width='" + CANVAS_WIDTH + "' height='" + CANVAS_HEIGHT + "'></canvas>");
    $(canvasElem).appendTo('body') ; 


    var canvas = canvasElem.get(0); 

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    context.fillRect(0,0,400,200);
}
```